# How to get only satisfy values from array

Tags: php, arrays

How to get only satisfy values from array? 
Example :

```
array('s_demo1','demox','demo2','s_demo2');
```

How to get values which is contain only `s_` ? I know that is possible with `strpos()` after foreach loop but any other way ?

Answer (score 2):

This would be an easy way of doing it:

```
$input = ['s_demo1','demox','demo2','s_demo2'];

$result = array_filter($input, function ($item) {
    return strpos($item, 's_') !== false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me using [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

```
function searchInArray($array, $search) 
{
    $search = str_replace( '\*', '.*?', preg_quote( $search, '/' ) );
    $result = preg_grep( '/^' . $search . '$/i', array_values( $array ) );

    return array_intersect($array, $result);
}

$arr = array('s_demo1','demox','demo2','s_demo2');
$searched = searchInArray($arr, 's_*');
var_dump($searched);
```

// Output
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "s_demo1" [3]=> string(7) "s_demo2" }

Comment: While you can use this, array_filter is imho best practice here (and much easier to read)